# Is there any way to export tables in a academic article using R?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

[image]

I have a data frame of observation, and I want to export the data frame to a `docx` file in the format like the picture. I can do this but in a hard way. Is there any more convenient way? Here are the packages I know that may help:`knitr` `printr` `bookdown`.
Say I have a data frame `mydata` like this:

```
Group CRP PCT
pos   1   7
pos   2   8
pos   3   9
neg   4   10
neg   5   11
neg   6   12
```

I want the `output` like this:

```
Group   CRP     PCT
pos     2(1~3)  8(7~9)
neg     5(4~6)  11(10~12)
p-value 0.00    0.00
```

I think the question is:

1. Given the `mydata` above, how can I transform it easily to `output`?
2. After I got the `output`, how can I export it to `docx` same as the format in the picture ?

Comment: Those packages are about creating things, not parsing/scraping things. You probably want something like [`pdftools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdftools/index.html) or [`tabulizer`](https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer).

Comment: I have updated my question to clarify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` to transform your data and `tableHTML` to create a table like the one in your question.

```
library(dplyr)
```

This function is used to summarise the `CRP` and `PCT` by `GROUP`.

```
fun <- function(x) {
  paste0(x[! x %in% c(min(x), max(x)) ], 
         "(",
         min(x),
         "~",
         max(x),
         ")")
}
```

Use that function in `summarise_all()` on `mydata` grouped by `Group` and sort the data by `Group`:

```
output <- mydata %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise_all(.funs = fun) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Group))
```

Then use `tableHTML` on `output` to create a scientific table:

```
library(tableHTML)
output %>% 
  tableHTML(rownames = FALSE,
            widths = rep(100, 3), 
            theme = 'scientific')
```

The result looks like this:

[image: tableHTML]

Answer (score 2):

I have been using `flextable` to export nice tables to Word, and after a few hours of pain and agony, I'm actually really pleased with it right now. Here's my R Markdown code chunk and the CSV file it's pulling the data from. You can download the CSV I used in this example from https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V1yMrz9cWX0YJwoUEJG8Nk01JPcLG-ZW

````
```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)
peoso <- read.csv("PEO-SO.csv",header=TRUE)
peoso %>% select(-grpindex) %>% 
     regulartable(col_keys=c("Type","col1","Number","col2", "Description")) %>% 
     merge_v(~Type) %>% autofit() %>% width(j=~Description, width=5) %>% empty_blanks()
```
````

The `width=` part lets you control how wide your columns are, so you can avoid the table being rendered off the page in Word. The `col1` and `col2` values are there as "dummy" columns to create a space in between columns in the table. Here's what a part of the final table looks like IN WORD so you can see how nicely it renders:

[image]

Comment: Do you know the differences between flextable and huxtable? I am wondering which one to use

Comment: I tried both of them, and `flextable` seems like it's easier to use. Probably not as powerful, but it seems to be less sensitive to the order of your pipe operations. I might be wrong... this is just based on gut feel.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "the hard way" but the code you generated above looks like it was created with LaTEX/sweave, or as a pdf with Rmarkdown.  Rmarkdown has a "Knit as" option.  Change this from pdf to word, and it will output your table in a word document.  Again, it won't quite look like that because that was created with LaTEX (either directly or in the background of a program).  I suggest checking out LaTEX to get a better idea of how to edit documents with that software.